# Not enough gas for initial manager cost

Tags: smart-contracts, kukai

```
Unrecognized error: proto.alpha.validate_operation.insufficient_gas_for_manager
```

I have been seeing this error out of nowhere anyone have any clue ? i am using kukai wallet ithacanet.kukai.com and my smart contract is deployed on ghostnet

Comment: Please provide more information if possible. Are providing more than `1000` on gas_limit? If you look at the network tab on your browser can you inspect the whole operation result?

Comment: Have you tried https://ghostnet.kukai.app/ instead?